# Prestashop 1.6 gamification module always adding and editing files

Tags: php, git, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am developing a custom Prestashop 1.6 module. I added all the website to git in order to track my changes. I created the .gitignore file using [gitignore.io](https://www.gitignore.io/).

The problem is there are always new added files and changed files in the gamification module.

[image: Gamification module changes]

Should I add the gamification module folder to .gitignore or there is another solution?

Comment: Well if you are developing a module only and the rest of the site is untouched, you can have only your module files in git.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the content of my `.gitignore` file:

```
# Created by .ignore support plugin (hsz.mobi)
### Prestashop template
# Private files
# The following files contain your database credentials and other personal data.

config/settings.*.php

# Cache, temp and generated files
# The following files are generated by PrestaShop.

admin2/autoupgrade/
/cache/
!/cache/index.php
!/cache/cachefs/index.php
!/cache/purifier/index.php
!/cache/push/index.php
!/cache/sandbox/index.php
!/cache/smarty/index.php
!/cache/tcpdf/index.php
config/xml/*.xml
/log/*
*sitemap.xml
themes/*/cache/
modules/*/config*.xml

# Site content
# The following folders contain product images, virtual products, CSV's, etc.

admin-dev/backups/
admin-dev/export/
admin-dev/import/
download/
/img/*
upload/

/modules/gamification/views/css/*.css
/themes/*/.sass-cache
/themes/*/.sass-cache/*.scssc
modules/homeslider/images/
!modules/homeslider/images/index.php
```

As you can see, I have added exclusion for gamification css files plus homeslider and sass cache files.

Comment: Good answer, but there are other changes in the data directory. In the end, I opted to just add my custom module to git.