# How to create the .gitignore file for prestashop 1.7

Tags: git, prestashop-1.7

I would like to know how I could create the .gitignore file for Prestashop 1.7, to be able to carry a good code version, both for the development environment, as well as to have it ready in production.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prestashop 1.6 gamification module always adding and editing files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42791372/prestashop-1-6-gamification-module-always-adding-and-editing-files)

Comment: https://www.gitignore.io/api/prestashop

Comment: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Prestashop.gitignore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the most complete Prestashop 1.7 .gitignore file I've seem.
If it has any flaws they are related to the fact it has too many entries, but that is not a problem :)

Source: https://gist.github.com/prestarocket/7870db5cbba8b841faf08563e11c0249

```
# Cache, temp and personal files

/.htaccess
*.log
npm-debug.log.*
.sass-cache/
/cache/*
download/*
/img/*
/log/*
/upload/*
vendor/*
docs/phpdoc-sf/
composer.lock
tests/Selenium/errorShots/
tests/Selenium/errorDumps/

/admin*/autoupgrade/*
/admin*/backups/*
/admin*/import/*

/admin*/import/*
!/admin*/import/.htaccess
!/admin*/import/index.php

themes/*/cache/*

# Config

config/settings.inc.php
config/settings.old.php
config/xml/*
config/themes/*
!config/xml/themes/default.xml
tests/Selenium/settings.js
themes/*/config/settings_*.json
app/config/parameters.old.yml
app/config/config.php

# Themes, modules and overrides

!modules/*
modules/config_*.xml
modules/ps_imageslider/images/*
!modules/ps_imageslider/images/index.php
modules/ps_banner/img/*
!modules/ps_banner/img/index.php

!override/*
/themes/StarterTheme

# Vendors and dependencies

bower_components/
node_modules/
composer.phar
php-cs-fixer
.grunt/*

# Translations and emails templates

translations/*
mails/*
!mails/fr/
themes/default-bootstrap/lang/*
themes/default-bootstrap/modules/*/translations/*.php
themes/default-bootstrap/mails/*
!themes/default-bootstrap/mails/fr/
themes/default-bootstrap/modules/*/mails/*
!themes/default-bootstrap/modules/*/mails/fr

# MISC

*sitemap.xml
/robots.txt

# Symfony

/app/bootstrap.php.cache
/app/cache/*
!app/cache/.gitkeep
/app/Resources/translations/*
!/app/Resources/translations/default
/app/test/cache/*
!app/test/cache/.gitkeep
/app/config/parameters.yml
/app/config/parameters.php
/app/logs/*
!app/logs/.gitkeep
/app/phpunit.xml
/bin/
/web/bundles/
/web/css/
/web/js/


# Created by https://www.gitignore.io/api/linux,osx,windows,sublimetext,phpstorm

### Linux ###
*~

# KDE directory preferences
.directory

# Linux trash folder which might appear on any partition or disk
.Trash-*


### OSX ###
.DS_Store
.AppleDouble
.LSOverride

# Icon must end with two \r
Icon


# Thumbnails
._*

# Files that might appear in the root of a volume
.DocumentRevisions-V100
.fseventsd
.Spotlight-V100
.TemporaryItems
.Trashes
.VolumeIcon.icns

# Directories potentially created on remote AFP share
.AppleDB
.AppleDesktop
Network Trash Folder
Temporary Items
.apdisk


### Windows ###
# Windows image file caches
Thumbs.db
ehthumbs.db

# Folder config file
Desktop.ini

# Recycle Bin used on file shares
$RECYCLE.BIN/

# Windows Installer files
*.cab
*.msi
*.msm
*.msp

# Windows shortcuts
*.lnk


### SublimeText ###
# cache files for sublime text
*.tmlanguage.cache
*.tmPreferences.cache
*.stTheme.cache

# workspace files are user-specific
*.sublime-workspace

# project files should be checked into the repository, unless a significant
# proportion of contributors will probably not be using SublimeText
# *.sublime-project

# sftp configuration file
sftp-config.json


### PhpStorm ###
# Covers JetBrains IDEs: IntelliJ, RubyMine, PhpStorm, AppCode, PyCharm, CLion, Android Studio

*.iml

## Directory-based project format:
.idea/

## File-based project format:
*.ipr
*.iws

## Plugin-specific files:

# IntelliJ
/out/

# mpeltonen/sbt-idea plugin
.idea_modules/

# JIRA plugin
atlassian-ide-plugin.xml

# Crashlytics plugin (for Android Studio and IntelliJ)
com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml
crashlytics.properties
crashlytics-build.properties

### NetBeans ###
nbproject/private/
build/
nbbuild/
dist/
nbdist/
nbactions.xml
nb-configuration.xml
.nb-gradle/

### Eclipse ###
.buildpath
.project
.settings/
.externalToolBuilders/
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I've used a lot this .gitignore:

```
# Private files
# The following files contain your database credentials and other personal data.

config/settings.*.php

# Cache, temp and generated files
# The following files are generated by PrestaShop.

admin-dev/autoupgrade/
/cache/*
!/cache/index.php
!/cache/*/
/cache/*/*
!/cache/cachefs/index.php
!/cache/purifier/index.php
!/cache/push/index.php
!/cache/sandbox/index.php
!/cache/smarty/index.php
!/cache/tcpdf/index.php
config/xml/*.xml
/log/*
*sitemap.xml
themes/*/cache/
modules/*/config*.xml

# Site content
# The following folders contain product images, virtual products, CSV's, etc.

admin-dev/backups/
admin-dev/export/
admin-dev/import/
download/
/img/*
upload/

# Also, I add this when I'm creating themes or modules
node_modules/

# And to be sure
.sass-cache/

# Code Editors
.vscode/
.idea/

.DS_Store
.DS_Store/
```

I took it directly from [Github's](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Prestashop.gitignore) gitignore templates repositories.

As a plus, you should check the documentation for making modules or themes [here](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS17/Developer+documentation).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This is not correct, the question said for 1.7, this ignore file works for 1.6.